# SwiftUI: How would I put a button on the same row with navigationTitle

Tags: swift, swiftui

How would I put a button on the same row with `navigationTitle` , an example is app store
What I've try so far (though unsure if there are any property that can specify that):

```
 NavigationView {
            
                Text("some content")
                    .navigationTitle("Store")
                        .navigationBarItems(trailing:  Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Text("Add")
                        }))

            }
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know why or how, the action of Button is disabled on that area, that you are asking! How ever you can put Image or text there, but you cannot have action. If that helps you then i can post the codes.

Comment: No, I'm asking how to put the button in that row, AppStore app has it, so I guess there must be a standard way.

Comment: https://uptech.team/blog/build-resizing-image-in-navigation-bar-with-large-title  , ideally I would like to have something like this. But I'm still a novice in SwiftUI and not sure how to put it.

Comment: that Link seems the best way in UIKit, but I think that is impossible in SwiftUI, maybe I am wrong, I am putting Button there but the action get broken for unknown reason!

Comment: retracted my answer, looks like it can be done but I would need to experiment.

Comment: @SergioBost: It is impossible, Since NavigationView is not pure in SwiftUI, it cary it`s behavior from UIKit, the best possible salvation would be implementing a customised way.

Comment: "It always seems impossible until it's done". I'm sure it is not impossible, there's even UIKit example. I just gotta understand how to use custom modifier/ or what ever the term is for bridging between SwiftUI & UIKit. Thanks for trying/helping guys, greatly appreciated. I'll keep you guys posted if I found something.